# Jquery drag drop and swapping on ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, swap

I have a square grid with 5*5 squares formed with `ul` which looks like a table. I want to swap two squares (ie) when i drag a square and drop it on another square both the squares should get swapped changing their positions. PFB the list which i want to know whether this can be done,

a) Swapping two squares by interchanging their index 
b) Stopping drag and drop on some squares

I tried sorting but it changes the postion of other squares as well. Any suggestion how this can be done in jquery??

Comment: anything can be done with jQuery !!! - Obviously kidding, but I'm wondering what you expect as answer. "Yes?" or a complete ready-to-go code ?

Comment: jQuery has a plugin for drag&drop. Have you seen this: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable ?